# Stack buttons vertically

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how can I make some buttons to stack vertically and not horizontally in css.

So, the html would be like:

```
<button>Test<button>
<button>Test<button>
<button>Test<button>
```

And those buttons will by default stack horizontally, what I want is to make them stack vertically (so everyone's on top of the next button).

Comment: Add `button { display: block; }` to your CSS. Buttons by default are `inline` elements, which will stay on the same line when possible. `block` elements on the other hand (like divs), will be forced to a new line. **As a separate note**, please do some research before asking questions - a quick search revealed plenty of duplicates.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Define the buttons as block-level elements. Also, note the use of the correct closing tag (`</button>`):

```css
button {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
<button>Test</button>
<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but now they aren't centered, any way on doing it?

Comment: @OscarArranz Give the buttons a width, and then use `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: You can use `margin: 0 auto` `0 for (top and bottom) auto for left and right

Answer (score 5):

`<buttons>` are inline-block elements by default. You can change that by styling the display to block instead:

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
<button>Test</button>
<button>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

as they have explained above, `buttons` element come with `inline` display property by default. you need to make `display: block;` to achieve your desired result:

```css
p{
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.button{
  background-color: #2a609a;
 width: 130px;
 height: 60px;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block-display button{
  margin-bottom:5px;
  display:block;
}

.button:hover{
  background-color: #32CD32;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="default-display">
  <p> buttons with defualt display: </p>
  </br>
  <button class="button">Button 1 </button>
  <button class="button">Button 2 </button>
  <button class="button">Button 3 </button>
</div>
</br>
<div class="block-display">
  <p> buttons with block display: </p>
  </br>
  <button class="button">Button 1 </button>
  <button class="button">Button 2 </button>
  <button class="button">Button 3 </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with your `css`

```
button {
    display: block;
}
```